# Modifying generated hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

I have to insert a figure (say Fig. 1) in my document, which already has 3 regions in it, which I would like to call as Fig. 1(a), Fig. 1(b) & Fig. 1(c). When I try to use \ref{Fig. 1} with hyperref package it generates hyperlink which shows Fig. 1 (or whatever count it generates for the given figure). Is there anyway I can modify this count number, depending on whether I want to refer to Fig. 1(a), Fig. 1(b) or Fig. 1(c)? In general I would like to add (a),(b) or (c) within hyperlink.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question depends very much on *how* the subfigures and their captions are generated. For instance, are they generated with the help of the `subfig` or `subcaption` packages? Have you created `\label` statements for each of the three subcaptions? (I gather you have created a `\label` statement with the main figure `\caption`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you employ the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment, you can generate the desired types of cross-references by (i) placing each graphic in a separate `subfigure` environment, (ii) providing `\caption` and `\label` statement in each `subfigure`, and (iii) using `\ref`-type calls to the labels associated with the respective subfigures (or, as you call them, "regions").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref} % for 'clever' cross-references.
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic1a}
\caption{Region A} \label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic1b}
\caption{Region B} \label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic1c}
\caption{Region C} \label{fig:1c}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A figure with three subfigures} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to \cref{fig:1}. Cross-references to \cref{fig:1a,fig:1b,,fig:1c}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.